# Binary operator ‘+=’ cannot be applied to two ‘CGPoint’ operands

Tags: swift, cgpoint

**Basic Syntax Problem** but, I can't solve it

```
func updateForeground(){
    worldNode.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "foreground", using: { node, stop in
        if let foreground = node as? SKSpriteNode{
            let moveAmount = CGPoint(x: -self.groundSpeed * CGFloat(self.deltaTime), y: 0)
            foreground.position += moveAmount
            if foreground.position.x < -foreground.size.width{
                foreground.position += CGPoint(x: foreground.size.width * CGFloat(self.numberOfForegrounds), y: 0)
            }    
        }
    })
}
```

Error on line `foreground.position += moveAmount` and

```
foreground.position += CGPoint(x: foreground.size.width * CGFloat(self.numberOfForegrounds), y: 0)
```

Everybody say use this code :

```
public func + (A: CGPoint, B: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
     return CGPoint(x: A.x + B.x, y: A.y + B.y)
}
```

OR;

something like this :

```
A.position.x += b.position.x
A.position.y += b.position.y
```

Please help ...

Comment: What's your question? Did you use the code code or the other solution? It's all about: What means "pointA+pointB"? And both solution should fix the issue.

Comment: It isn't clear what you need help with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `+` operator is not defined for `CGPoint`, so you cannot use that or `+=`. You already found the right function you have to define, just make sure you actually use it. You can actually go one step further and also define the `+=` operator for `CGPoint`.

```
extension CGPoint {
    public static func +(lhs:CGPoint,rhs:CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
        return CGPoint(x: lhs.x + rhs.x, y: lhs.y + rhs.y)
    }

    public static func +=(lhs:inout CGPoint, rhs:CGPoint) {
        lhs = lhs + rhs
    }
}

func updateForeground(){
    worldNode.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "foreground", using: { node, stop in
        if let foreground = node as? SKSpriteNode {
            let moveAmount = CGPoint(x: -self.groundSpeed * CGFloat(self.deltaTime), y: 0)
            foreground.position += moveAmount
            if foreground.position.x < -foreground.size.width {
                foreground.position += CGPoint(x: foreground.size.width * CGFloat(self.numberOfForegrounds), y: 0)
            }    
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Yeah! Thank`s a lot , Dávid Pásztor

Answer (score 0):

**You want to use '+='** operator .

To do this:

```
func updateForeground() {

    worldNode.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "foreground", using: { node, stop in
    if let foreground = node as? SKSpriteNode{
        let moveAmount = CGPoint(x: -self.groundSpeed * CGFloat(self.deltaTime), y: 0)
        foreground.position.x += moveAmount.x
        foregorund.postion.y += moveAmount.y

        if foreground.position.x < -foreground.size.width {
          foreground.position.x += foreground.size.width * CGFloat(self.numberOfForegrounds)
        }    
    }
})
```

Comment: Why you all downvote? This code is working correctly